# Rspec not matching title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have the following spec

```
describe "user enters 150 into time" do
 before do
   fill_in "workout[total_time]", with: "150"
   click_button "Update Workout"
 end
  it "should be on profile page" do
    save_and_open_page
    page.should have_selector("h1", text: "Profile")
    page.should have_selector("title", text: "Profile")
  end
end
```

It's failing with the following message:

```
Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: expected to find css "title" with text "Profile" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

The source code (from `save_and_open_page`) contains this `head` section:

```
<head>
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
 <title>Profile
 </title>
 <meta content="Composer Delete" name="description">
 <link href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Here is the view:

```
- content_for :title do
  Profile
%h1 Profile
%table.table.table-striped
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
  %tbody
  - current_user.workouts.each do |workout|
    %tr
      %td= link_to workout.name, workout
      %td= link_to "Edit", edit_profile_workout_url(workout)
      %td= link_to "Remove", profile_workout_url(workout), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"
= link_to "Create New Workout", new_profile_workout_url
```

And the `content_for` is from `layouts/application.html.haml`:

```
%title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Composer Delete"
```

The title of the page is being displayed as "Profile".

Any ideas why this spec is failing?

Rails 3.2.3

Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Capybara 2.0 bug (or feature :) . Try to use previous versions (1.1.2 works fine for me).

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/844

pull request with has_title? matcher:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/844